# batch command - find multiple texts in seperate lines and output them as columns

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, text

i am trying to make an inventory of installed software in domain PCs by following reg command

Reg Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S ^| Find /I "DisplayName"

I am using Find /I "DisplayName" to get software-name. I also need the version number (and may be few more fields later), but its in another line as DisplayVersion.

Since I am running this on multiple computers, my script looks like this:

```
    for /f %%i in (computers_ALL.txt) do (

for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%j in ('psexec \\%%i Reg Query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S ^| Find /I "DisplayName"') do (
    echo x64 %%i %%l >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
    )

for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%j in ('psexec \\%%i Reg Query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S ^| Find /I "DisplayName"') do (
    echo x86 %%i %%l >>%OUTPUT_FILE%
    )
)
```

Now I can only find DisplayName. How can I find DisplayVersion which is on another line and add it to second column? My output will be like,

ComputerName, Platform (32-64 bit), Software Name, Software Version

I can take care upto software-name, but having difficulty to get version and put it on second column. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "output_file=u:\report.txt"
DEL "%output_file%" /F /Q
for /f %%i in (q41887529.txt) do (
 SET "compname=%%i"
 CALL :clrsoft
 FOR %%z IN (\ \Wow6432Node\) DO ( 
  for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%j in (
   'Reg Query HKLM\Software%%zMicrosoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /S ^| Findstr /I "DisplayName DisplayVersion HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\"'
   ) do (
    IF /i "%%j"=="Displayname" (
     SET "softname=%%l"
    ) ELSE (
     IF /i "%%j"=="Displayversion" (
      SET "softver=%%l"
     ) ELSE (
      CALL :report %%z
    )
   )
  )
 REM processed all data - final report
 CALL :report %%z
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:: Report routine parameters : 
:: %1 indicates x64 ("\") or x86 (\Wow6432Node\)

:report
IF NOT DEFINED softname GOTO clrsoft
IF "%1"=="\" (
 ECHO "%compname%",x64,"%softname%","%softver%">>"%output_file%"
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO "%compname%",x86,"%softname%","%softver%">>"%output_file%"
)
:clrsoft
SET "softname="
SET "softver="
GOTO :EOF
```

Naturally, you'd need to set up your own output filename. I've also removed the `psexec \\%%i` and set up my machine name in `q41887529.txt` for testing on my machine.

Since the only difference between the queries is the node, I combined the steps and controlled them using `%%z`.

Clear the tempvars, then process each return line for one of the three target strings.

If it's a name, then call `:report` to report any accumulated data, then record the name

If it's a version, record the version and since this should now give us a pair, report it.

If it's neither, then it must be a new key, so report what we have so far.

The wart is that the version need not exist - and the final entry may be versionless, so we try reporting again to ensure any accumulated data is output.

I've revised this now and replaced the original.

It will report the machine name extracted from the file and I believe that the often-missing version number has been fixed - the order of name and version are unpredictable, so the report is triggered with the data accumulated between instances of `HKEY_` and at the very end.

Comment: thanks. this is definitely better way to extract the data I am needing. I have slight issues though. Computer-name is not coming and also the version number. 32/64 platform and only software-name is being saved into output file.

Answer (score 0):

Following script works against a local Windows machine. Adapting it for a list `computers_ALL.txt` instead of `"%computername%"` and adding `psexec \\%_comp%` should be a simple task.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "OUTPUT_FILE=%temp%\41887529.txt"
for /F %%i in ("%computername%") do (
  set "_comp=%%i"
  call :proHive "x64" "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
  call :proHive "x86" "\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
)

rem debugging output
type "%OUTPUT_FILE%"
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:proHive
rem %1 platform
rem %2 registry key
>>"%OUTPUT_FILE%" (
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('
  Reg Query "HKLM%~2" /S /V DisplayName ^| Find /I "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE%~2"
  ') do (
    set "_DisplayName="
    set "_DisplayVersion="
    for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%j in ('
      Reg Query "%%G" ^| Findstr /I "DisplayName\> DisplayVersion\>"') do set "_%%j=%%l"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
      echo %_comp%,%~1,!_DisplayVersion!,!_DisplayName!
    ENDLOCAL
)
)
goto :eof
```